# Relative clauses preceded by a fronted preposition

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

How would you say:

> In Paris there are famous bridges to stroll under

I was thinking

> À Paris il y a des ponts sous lesquels on peut flâner

The wider issue here is, how is it best to say phrases such as

- with which
- under which
- above which
- in which
- through which
- etc.

Answer (score 10):

Your translation is correct (apart from missing the translation for *famous*, but I guess that's not the point here). As for the other phrases, they respectively translate to

> - avec lequel
> - sous lequel
> - sur lequel / au-dessus duquel
> - dans lequel
> - au travers duquel

You'll just have to replace *lequel* or *duquel* with the agreed form if needed

> - lequel / laquelle / lesquels / lesquelles
> - duquel / de laquelle / desquels / desquelles